# Mobile app two Game-Engines in one return? Merging Game-Engine into another Game-Engine?

Tags: react-native, game-engine

I'm trying to have a game where you control a dot with your finger and there are blocks that fall from the top of screen and you collect them
Problem: I can see the box falling and the dot on the screen I cant move the dot, when I take away the block falling I can then move the dot

I've tried to make two game engines in one return and I can only see the game engine that's at the top, almost like the screen for the dot overlaps the block where you cant see it --this could be because of stylesheet(just a thought)

I've tried to import the class into the  for the dot, that's when I can see both but I cant move the dot

```
 class GameScreen extends PureComponent {

constructor(){
    super();
}

  render() {
  return (      
  <Falling/>,
  <Testdot/>                     
);
}
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
container: {
flex: 1,
backgroundColor: "#FFF"
}
});

class Testdot extends PureComponent {

constructor(){
    super();
}

render() {
return (

  <GameEngine
    systems={[MoveFinger]} // We can add as many systems as needed
    entities={{
      1: { position: [165,  450], renderer: <Finger/>} }}>
    <StatusBar hidden={true} />    
    </GameEngine>

);
}
}

class Falling extends React.Component {

        constructor(props){
        super(props);

    this.gameEngine = null;
    this.entities = this.setupWorld();
}

setupWorld = () => {

    let engine = Matter.Engine.create({ enableSleeping: false });
    let world = engine.world;

    let box = Matter.Bodies.rectangle(Constants.MAX_WIDTH / 4, Constants.MAX_HEIGHT / 2, 50, 90);

    Matter.World.add(world, [box]);

    return{
      physics: { engine: engine, world: world },
      box: { body: box, size: [40,90], color: 'green', renderer: Box }
    }
}

render(){
  return (

      <GameEngine
          ref={(ref) => { this.gameEngine = ref; }}
          systems={[Physics]}
          entities={this.entities} />

      );
    }
  }
```

I want to be able to move the circle dot with both the falling block and the circle on the screen, but I cant move the dot when both are on screen

Comment: Why do you use two game engines? I think, It will work correctly you should use one game engine and it is possible for this.

Comment: When I use one game engine only one of the classes show up for an example if I use the Circle class and the Block class in one game engine the one that’s on top always displays and the one below it doesn’t <Testdot/>, <Falling/>  (the test block will show because it’s first, if I put falling before it, then falling will show and not testdot

Comment: This is my current Snack.io the whole project, if anyone needs to view what is happening https://snack.expo.io/@tracegsheets/color-storm-updated